# Long-term viability of induced parthenogenesis

Tags: parasitology, asexual-reproduction, haplodiploid

### Short version:

Some parasitic bacteria, such as *Wolbachia*, cause hosts from sexually-reproducing insect species to reproduce asexually instead, with an all-female line. Sometimes, all members of the species end up reproducing in this way - see e.g. [*Encarsia formosa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encarsia_formosa) wasps. How many generations can this remain viable before the effects of

- reduced genetic diversity/inbreeding
- possible reduced parasite resistance
- etc.

take their toll?

If that's too vague a question, what is the longest time/no. of generations that induced-parthenogenetic species have been known to survive?

**NOTE: This only applies to *induced* parthenogenesis resulting from e.g. parasitic bacteria infections. Not to naturally-occurring parthenogenesis.**

### Full version:

Certain parasitic bacteria, such as *[Wolbachia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolbachia)* can induce [thelytokous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thelytoky) [parthenogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenogenesis) in their [haplodiploid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplodiploid) insect hosts. The infection is passed on down the generations, from mother to daughters. Eventually, this can lead to [speciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speciation).

(In non-technical language... the effect of this is that infected female insects lay unfertilised eggs, which hatch exclusively into females, which later on lay unfertilised eggs which hatch into more female insects...

Members of a species which previously reproduced sexually now reproduce asexually, and the asexually-reproducing members of the species may eventually diverge so much from the others genetically that they become a separate species.)

All Hymenoptera (ants, wasps etc.) are haplodiploid.

One would expect that this would reduce genetic diversity in the infected population. A species which previously reproduced sexually, and now reproduces entirely asexually, might be expected long-term to lose biological fitness as a result of [inbreeding depression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inbreeding_depression). See also: ["Muller's ratchet"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muller%27s_ratchet)

However, a [2001 paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12009809) investigated the effects of *Wolbachia*-induced parthenogenesis on *Trichogramma* wasp species, comparing such wasps to those that reproduced sexually and to those that were naturally parthenogenetic. Fewer of the infected wasp embryos survived to adulthood, but this was due to direct effects of the infestation on embryonic growth. Inbreeding depression was not a factor.

A [2000 paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Raymond_Klaassen2/publication/12497286_Infectious_parthenogenesis/links/0046352028444dd0e2000000.pdf) also noted that *Wolbachia* can be horizontally transmitted through the sharing of a common food source, and stated:

> horizontal transfer of parthenogenesis-inducing Wolbachia among offspring of infected females offers the potential for recombination between different Wolbachia variants and thus for circumventing Muller's ratchet.

Though I think that would only apply to the bacteria, not its host.

A notable example of *Wolbachia*-induced parthenogenesis is the chalcidoid wasp species [*Encarsia formosa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encarsia_formosa). I don't know how long this has existed as a distinct species. Antibiotic treatment to kill the *Wolbachia* can restore their ability to give birth to males.

Is there a theoretical limit on the number of generations an induced-partheogenetic species should be able to survive? And what is the longest amount of time that any such species has been observed to survive?

### Sources:

[Tagami, Y., Miura, K., & Stouthamer, R. (2001). How does infection with parthenogenesis-inducing Wolbachia reduce the fitness of Trichogramma?. Journal of Invertebrate Pathology, 78(4), 267-271.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12009809) (Paywalled, unfortunately.)

[Huigens, M. E., Luck, R. F., Klaassen, R. H. G., Maas, M. F. P. M., Timmermans, M. J. T. N., & Stouthamer, R. (2000). Infectious parthenogenesis. Nature, 405(6783), 178-179.](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Raymond_Klaassen2/publication/12497286_Infectious_parthenogenesis/links/0046352028444dd0e2000000.pdf)

Stouthamer, R., & Luck, R. F. (1993). Influence of microbe‐associated parthenogenesis on the fecundity of Trichogramma deion and T. pretiosum. Entomologia Experimentalis et Applicata, 67(2), 183-192. (Paywalled.)

Comment: What a good question!I think that Wolbachia infections could be sustainable on the long term.Lots of species are currently infected by Wolbachia (looks like at least 25% of all insects species could host Wolbachia) and some scientists call it a symbiosis rather than an infection.In other words, I think Wolbachia doesn't lower the evolutionary success of its hosts.

Comment: @Zafalija Bear in mind that *Wolbachia* infection affects different hosts in different ways. In some areas, there are species with 100% of the population infected, but no apparent symptoms. (Not even *Wolbachia*'s famous biasing of sex ratios.) For example, in the Carpathian Basin, three of my favourite butterfly species - the Large Blue (*Phengaris arion*), Alcon Blue (*Phengaris alcon*) and Mountain Alcon Blue (*Phengaris rebeli*) are all 100% infected. And in the UK, 19 populations of another butterfly, *Euphydryas aurinia*, also have 100% Wolbachia prevalence, without any apparent effect!

Comment: Sources for the above: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/276509070_Controversial_patterns_of_Wolbachia_infestation_in_the_social_parasitic_Maculinea_butterflies_Lepidoptera_Lycaenidae and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphydryas_aurinia

Comment: @Zafalija OK. I just wanted to get across that my question is explicitly about host species that it induces parthenogenesis in. It doesn't do that in any of the butterfly species with 100% infection that I mentioned.

Comment: And Wolbachia can be lost of course, e.g https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6493766/

Loss of cytoplasmic incompatibility in Wolbachia-infected Aedes aegypti under field conditions

Comment: I knew about entire populations infected by Wolbachia.I was trying to say that Wolbachia infection doesn't have any negative impact on the survival of the species due to lack of genetic variability; lots of species have been infected for centuries without becoming extinct, so I guess their altered sex ratio is not an important factor for survival, at least until some male survives: having a unisex population is obviously a serious evolutionary threat.

Comment: Since wolbachia infections can be "entirely cleared" as stated by @PolypipeWrangler, you won't have entire species with no males at all.Maybe you could find some populations totally infected by wolbachia, but since wolbachia infections are 'reversible' some male could appear here and there, restoring a little genetic variability in our pool.Please notice that parthenogenesis could be beneficial in some cases: it seems that lots of invasive species are parthenogenetic (https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=it&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=parthenogenetic+invasive+species&btnG=&oq=parthenogenetic+i)

Comment: @Zafalija You mention "species infected for centuries". Did any of these become parthenogenetic as a result of the infection? If so, could you tell me the names of these species? Thanks!

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler Thanks. But that scenario relied on the high temperatures in the locality, and not all species with Wolbachia will live in regions that get that hot.

Comment: Check this: https://www.karger.com/Article/Abstract/104228                                     Wolbachia was discovered in 1924.It is likely that it has been around for centuries, if not millennia, before its discovery.Also, @PolypipeWrangler's comment pointed out that wolbachia can be lost.We surely do know that it can be lost due to high temperatures, but you can't exclude that wolbachia could be lost due to other environmental factors.Please notice that wolbachia could actually improve the fitness of certain species!

Comment: @Zafalija I've looked at the abstract (I can't read the full article due to the paywall). It mentions Culex pipiens (but misspells it "pipientis"). Wolbachia induces cytoplasmic incompatibility in that species, but that's not the same thing as parthenogenesis.

Comment: That abstract was meant to be a reference to the fact that wolbachia has been discovered in 1924, not to parthenogenesis induced by wolbachia.If it's true that wolbachia has been around for centuries, if not millennia, there could be lots of species infected by wolbachia on the long term, with its effects being parthenogenesis or cytoplasmic incompatibility (which could lead to rapid speciation events), but I don't think there's enough literature about this.These are only my speculations, but keep in mind that centuries and millennia are nothing in evolutionary time, hence I think

Comment: that lots of species have been hosting wolbachia for long periods of time (maybe losting it after some environmental change), and the fact that we currently know about species infected by these bacteria means that it isn't awful in evolutionary terms.This theory is probably true if wolbachia is really old, while it's totally erroneous if wolbachia is recent.